# ELB routing strategies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

The default routing strategy is Round-Robin with some IP/session-based stickiness. Are any other strategies possible? (Route53 has weighted round robin, but ELB doesn't seem to)

Does round-robin imply that you should absolutely use the exact same size of EC2 instances for all servers behind ELB? (Using some large and some small would mean the small ones might get overloaded while the large ones have resources to spare)

Is it practically possible to switch out EC2 instances one-by-one to a larger size without downtime?

Answer (score 2):

ELBs only support session (cookie) based stickiness, not IP. When you create an ELB, DNS uses Round-Robin to route to a specific ELB instance. The ELB itself uses a least outstanding requests routing algorithm to route requests to individual instances. This is documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/how-elb-works.html

> Does round-robin imply that you should absolutely use the exact same
>   size of EC2 instances for all servers behind ELB?

Yes

> Is it practically possible to switch out EC2 instances one-by-one to a
>   larger size without downtime?

Yes. Add one or more larger instances to the pool. Once the ELB shows the new instances as in-service remove an equal number of smaller instances from the pool, using [connection draining](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-conn-drain.html) to allow any outstanding requests to complete. Repeat until all smaller instances are replaced.

Note that whenever an instance is removed from your load balancer the HTTP sessions on that instance will be destroyed, possibly causing any users "stuck" to that server to be logged out from your website. To prevent this you would have to use some sort of shared session mechanism.